# Why does React Router history push fail to render new component sometimes?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router-v4

I've seen this problem asked before on Stack Overflow, but the case was that the history was updated but the new component was NEVER rendered. In my case, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I'm using the history object that is passed down to my component via props.

I have some logic for logging in a user and after that promise has been solved, I use the code below to send them to the home page after the login is successful.

```
this.props.history.push("/home");
```

The strange thing is that sometimes they're redirected correctly, but other times the browser URL is updated and the home component is NOT rendered.

Here's the file that renders my routes:

```html
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/home' authed={this.state.authUser} component={Home}/>
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/new' authed={this.state.authUser} component={NewPhone}/>
  <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Root}/>
  <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup}/>
</Switch>
```

Here is also the PrivateRoute component that I used:

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed,...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    authed !== null ? (
      <Component {...props} authed={authed} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: "/login",
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )} />
);
```

If any more information is needed, I'll be glad to provide it. Thanks a lot

Comment: It will be hard to figure out what could be wrong without seeing your component that renders the Routes.

Comment: @Tholle it's just an App component with a Switch and my routes. All of my Routes are rendered by passing the component via the components prop. I'm not using the render prop. I'll update this with my exact code when I get home. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Providing the route calls for a new component to mount then it will update. If it's calling an already mounted component with the new URL then my guess is that it is only doing a shallow check of the component props. You can manually force the update using `shouldComponentUpdate`, but know that once you declare this function you need to tell it when to update in all cases